# Laravel relationship is returning null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-4

i want to create simple Relationships for find user's profile information in database with `User` model.

in User.php i have:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    ...
    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('UserProfile');
    }
    ...
}
```

and in model/UserProfile.php:

```
class UserProfile extends Eloquent{

    protected $table='user_profile';
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

in database `users.user_id` and `user_profile.user_id` is `1000`.

I want to access to user profile with this line in controller:

```
public function getIndex()
{

    $profile = $user->profile;
    dd( $profile );
    die;
}
```

Result of `dd()` is :

```
NULL
```

whats my Relationship problem?

Comment: Does the user_profile row exist in the DB?

Comment: Where does your `getIndex()` get its `$user` from?

Comment: @Unnawut in ProfileController to access user profile

Comment: And I assume `var_dump($user->user_id)` is giving you the correct user id right? Have you tried `$this->hasOne('UserProfile', 'user_id', 'user_id')` in your `profile()`?

Answer (score 4):

looks like the relationships aren't loaded.

either try loading them by using [eager-loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
User::with('user_profile')->get();
```

or load them later with lazy-loading:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load('user_profile');
```

also since you're using another primary key property than `id`, you need to specify it (or in your relation declaration):

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Comment: I don't think eager loading has anything to do with this. But setting the primary key should.

Comment: its so frustrating to learn about this.. laravel is just not mature enough

Answer (score 1):

For your `users` table you are using a different primary key other than `id` as expected so in your `User` model you should explicitly declare the `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'` and also you may use this:

```
// Not tested with same foreign and local key
return $this->hasOne('UserProfile', 'user_id', 'user_id');
```

But it's better to keep the both keys different, probably you can rename the `users.user_id` to `users.id`. If you rename the `users.user_id` to `users.id` then everything will work without any changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had suffered from the same issue and the reason was there was a whitespace after the column which would be used as relation. Simply deleting it solved. May not be related to your question directly, but I believe this may save some hours of people who reach this page through a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was eager loading just as @zwacky suggested:

> or load them later with lazy-loading:

```
>$user = Auth::user();
>$user->load('user_profile');
```

This will do the solution when `user_profile` has just been created and you need to access `user_profile` through `$user` in another part of your code. 
Looks like laravel does not update the parent model immediately.